# Could not find artifact commons-codec:commons-codec:zip:1.10 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am newbie to grails/groovy. In my grails app, i added a new dependency to **BuildConfig.groovy** as below

```
compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
```

When I try to start my app, i get the below error

> | Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact
>   commons-codec:commons-codec:zip:1.10 in grailsCentral
>   (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)

Please help.

Comment: Did you add that in the `plugins` or `dependencies` section of `BuildConfig.groovy`? You should have added it into the `dependencies` section.

Comment: Your suggestion helped and it solved. I added it in Plugins by mistake instead of dependencies.

Comment: Added it as an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error it would appear you have added this into the `plugins` section of your `BuildConfig.groovy` when you should add it into the `dependencies` section. Doing so will resolve this issue.